# PDF generation error with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm having a strange issue when trying to copy text from a generated PDF. Following are the steps,

- Generate the PDF using wicked_pdf gem
- PDF generates **correctly**
- When I do a select all on the PDF, the places it has letters `fi`, or `ffi` is not selecting
- happens only in the server (linux), works fine
  in local (mac)

I'm using

- `wicked_pdf` gem
- `wkhtmltopdf` ver 0.12
- Fonts 'Noto Sans SC', 'Noto Sans'
- ruby 2.2.3
- rails 4.2.5.2

Below is what is happening when I do a select all.

[image]

Comment: This is a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) issue, possibly because of the desired font is not installed on the server.

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa, I'll have a look 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be due to having `text-rendering` set to `optimizeLegibility` in your css file.
Remove this line:

`text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;`

and you should be gold :)

Reference from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering):

*"One very visible effect is optimizeLegibility, which enables ligatures (ff, fi, fl etc.) in text smaller than 20px for some fonts (for example, Microsoft's Calibri, Candara, Constantia and Corbel or the DejaVu font family)."*

Note that I had the same problem with the Noto font and `optimizeLegibility` definitely affects it.